# How to tell JavaScript to execute a function after an element has been loaded?

Tags: javascript, dom

How to tell JavaScript to execute a function after an element has been loaded w/out any external library?
Normally I have to bring the `<script>` tag after the element itself to work with DOM calls.

Comment: What's wrong with bringing the `<script>` tag after the element?

Comment: how are you loading said `element`?

Comment: @onteria absolutely nothing. I just wanted to know the other options.

Comment: @hunter it's a simple div element in a plain html format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can utilize the `document.onload` and `window.onload` methods
For example:

```
window.onload = function(){
   //do some stuff 
}
```

Comment: this works, but thats after the entire page was loaded and not only one element

Answer (score 40):

If you don't want to wait for the full page to load you can also poll for the element's existence:

```
function myFunc() {
  if (document.getElementById('myElement')) {
    // do stuff
  } else {
    setTimeout(myFunc, 15);
  }
}
```

Comment: Would this solution slow down the browser? Would be great to have an onload-element listener, for example, to format html from other source before insertion, in an efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

Putting your **script** just above the body tag is a valid option. If the element in question supports it, you can also use it's onload event. You could also attach to the onload event of the window or document.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is adding `<img src="" onerror="callback()">` *after* the element and execute codes on `onerror` event:

```js
function func(img) {
    console.log("Element loaded");
    img.parentNode.removeChild(img);
    document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = "Just loaded";
}
```

```html
<p id="hello">Not loaded yet</p>
<img onerror="func(this)" src="" style="display:none">
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
function onElementReady(querySelector,callBack) {
  if (document.querySelector(querySelector)) {
    callBack();
  } else {
    setTimeout(()=>onElementReady.call(this,...arguments), 100);
  }
}
```

Usage example:

```
onElementReady("#my-element-id",()=>{alert("your element is ready!")})
```